# several HTML buttons calling the same JS function but with different arguments

Tags: javascript, onclick

After receiving an unknown number of string arrays from the server I am trying to print each array as a table and each table should have the option to be displayed or not. JS function that makes the table and the HIDE/SHOW-button:

```
function printTable(data,color,name){
    var html = "<table border='1|1' id =";
    html += "'"+name+"'" ;
    html += " style='background-color:";
    html += color + "'";
    html += ">";
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<th>"+name+"</th>";

    html += "</tr>";
    console.log("length is: "+ data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (data[i]) {
            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";

            html += "</tr>";

        }
    }
        html+="</table>";
        console.log(html);
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.id = name+"Table";
        table.cellSpacing = "10";
        table.innerHTML = html;
        table.setAttribute("bgcolor",color);
        table.style.display = 'block';
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.id = name;
        var t = document.createTextNode("Show/Hide");
        button.appendChild(t);
        button.onclick = showHide;
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(table);
        div.id = name+"Div";
        div.appendChild(button);
        document.getElementById('listsDiv').appendChild(div);

}
```

I also wrote this function the hide/show the table:

```
 function showHide(name){
    var str = name + "Table" ;
    var x = document.getElementById(str);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The thing is, that the onClick attribute of each button does not get the function as it should. 
How can I use the same function, but with different parameter (the name) in each button?

thanks

Comment: can you provide a JSfiddle or atleast the HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Inside the [`onClick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) you have access to the [`Event`](http://Event) object. The event object is *always* the first argument and will pass in *automatically* to it. In your case `name` is the `event` object. 
Trought the `Event` you have access to the `currentTarget` - the element you clicked.
Additionaly you can use `this` inside an `eventHanlder` like onClick to get the current target.

### Code

```
function showHide(event) {
    var elementId = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name') + 'Table'
    // var elementId = this.getAttribute('name') + 'Table'
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var displayStyle = element.style.display
    if (displayStyle  === 'none') {
        displayStyle  = 'block';
    } else {
        displayStyle  = 'none';
    }
}
```

*small trick..* the `if statement` could be writen shorter with the [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
displayStyle === 'none' ? block' : 'none'
```

### Example

```js
document.querySelector('#btnPeter').onclick = showHideWithEvent
document.querySelector('#btnGeorg').onclick = showHideWithThis

function showHideWithEvent(event) {
    var name = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')
    console.log(name)
}

function showHideWithThis() {
    var name = this.getAttribute('name')
    console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<button id="btnPeter" name="peter">Peter</button>
<button id="btnGeorg" name="georg">Georg</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button.id is the argument you're trying to pass to the function, you can rewrite your code as follow:

```
function showHide(){
    var str = this.id + "Table" ;
    var x = document.getElementById(str);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the code you've written is correct, it should be enough to change your `showHide` function so that it itself returns a new function. This way you can easily create different "version" of the same `onclick` callback function.

```
function showHide(name){
// return a callback where the name is already set
  return function() {
    var str = name + "Table" ;
    var x = document.getElementById(str);
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };
}
```

Then, in your loop, you call this function to generate a new callback for each of the tables.

```
button.onclick = showHide(name);
```

Comment: I think `button.onclick = showHide(name);` would be called immediately

Comment: Correct. That's the point, since the function returns exactly the callback you want. It's a function returning new functions.